# Laravel specify any date

Tags: php, laravel, date, time, php-carbon

Is there any way where I can set any date I wanted in Laravel. I have to demonstrate a testing and I need to check if the code works for different date. I want to specify the date in my Laravel project to ensure that the code runs in the specify date. I search a lot of question and non of it answered my question most of the question are on how to change the date format.

Comment: What code are you talking about that you need to test to make sure it "works" for a different date?

Comment: So I have a code that uses a php-carbon. It will compare if the current date is the same as the date set. If the current date is the same as the date that have been set. It will display the content

Comment: If you're using `\Carbon\Carbon::now()`  or `\Carbon\Carbon::today()` these will reflect the current time or the current day. If you need to be able to test your application, regarding how it will render and look during a specific date, all you'd need to do is feed in a different date. For example in an application I worked on a year or two ago, I needed a way to test something how it will look in a week. So I added in an optional query string parameter to the application. If present, it would add extra days to the carbon timestamp to emulate waiting multiple days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbon - Testing Aids:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing

Allows you to mock the time in tests with `Carbon::setTestNow()`

And see Carbonite for more advanced features:
https://github.com/kylekatarnls/carbonite

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to run some function on specific date/time, which you will set, for this you have to put CRON for that function and you have to specify there a date/time in laravel.